# Weird output of strlen on int to char conversion in C

Tags: c, string, type-conversion, int

Why does the code below print the length as 2 instead of 1?

```
int i = 2;

char tmp = i + '0';

printf("len of %s is %zu \n ",&tmp,strlen(&tmp));
```

Comment: `tmp` is a `char` with value `'2'`.  The expression `&tmp` yields a pointer to that char, but that is not a *string*, because there is no terminator in the (equivalent of a) one-character array to which it points.  As a result, the `strlen()` call exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the code below print ...

Because your code exhibits undefined behavior, and could do *anything* (including crashing instead of printing anything at all).

A *contract* for `strlen` says that you must pass a pointer to a `NUL`-terminated string to it. But `&tmp` is *not* a pointer to such a string.

To fix this, you might do:

```
char tmp[2];
tmp[0] = i + '0';
tmp[1] = '\0';  // The NUL terminator

printf("len of %s is %zu \n ", tmp, strlen(tmp));
```

Comment: But here i necessarily needs to be a single digit number, what do you do when i gets to double digits?

Comment: @PrathuBaronia Are you trying to implement `itoa`? Obviously, you'll need larger temporary buffer (which should still be properly `NUL`-terminated).

Comment: I am sort of doing the same thing as in itoa as a part of my problem but I want to clarify about adding the '0' thing. Is there a substitute for that for two and three digit numbers smaller than 255 ofcourse.

Comment: @PrathuBaronia Sorry, I don't understand your question. You should probably start a new question with "what you are trying to achieve", "what you have written so far", and your question about terminating `\0` (which should still be there).